# JSR-310 Year mapped to TINYBLOB in MySQL

Tags: java, hibernate, java-time

Well, mine is a silly question.

With Hibernate 5.1 (5.2 the same) my `Year` column is mapped to `tinyblob` instead of the intuitive `int` column one would expect. Other JSR-310 columns are successfully mapped.

E.g.

```
@Column(name = "ANNO_PROTOCOLLO", nullable = true)
protected Year annoProtocollo;

@Column(name = "CREATED", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = true)
protected LocalDateTime created = LocalDateTime.now();
```

The first column is mapped to `tinyblob` but the second is **correctly** mapped to `datetime` which is the SQL standard for such values.

Again, my question is silly because nothing prevents me to declare that Year column as an int, but I wanted to understand the reason behind this and if there is a way that takes *less than 3 lines of code* to map Year to int. Since I need to work on multiple databases, I cannot accept `@Column(columnDefinition)` and if that is the only solution I will just use Integer and live with that, as I did before

Comment: JDBC defines the data type mapping for `LocalDate`, `LocalDateTime`, `LocalTime`, `OffsetDateTime` and `OffsetTime`; the type `Year` is not such a type (there is no equivalent type in the SQL standard).

Comment: Thanks @MarkRotteveel, your comment clearly points the situation out. Now, from the speculation point of view, would you **personally** agree that `int` could be a correct mapping? Just for discussion purposes, I am modifying my column to Integer asap

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Is that in Java 9? Because JDBC 4.2 (Java 8) doesn't define mappings for the new `java.time` classes, as far as I can find.

Comment: @Andreas no, it is specified in Java 8/JDBC 4.2 (check the specification, not the apidoc); however it doesn't define separate getters and setters, just using get/setObject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *simple* reason is that they didn't provide a specific mapping for `Year`, so you're getting the default mapping of object serialization to/from bytes, i.e. a BLOB.

You can implement a custom type to provide a mapping.
See [Hibernate Domain Model Mapping Guide - Custom BasicTypes](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/mappingGuide/en-US/html_single/#basic-custom).